# ¿Por que no puedo ver los objetos sys. de SQL Server?

Tags: sql

Buenas tardes,

Tengo una inquietud, no sé cual sea la razón del por que no puedo visualizar las vistas pertenecientes al esquema "sys", de modo que salió el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

... cuando hice esta consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM master.sys.database_permissions AS dp   
JOIN sys.system_objects AS so  
ON dp.major_id = so.object_id  
WHERE dp.class = 1 AND so.parent_object_id = 0 ;  
GO
```

Y pues me está trayendo problemas con códigos más grandes, incluso en el explorador del Management Studio no figuran las vistas con esquema sys. (Ejemplo sys.table) solo aparecen los que tienen esquema dbo.

A que creen que se deba.

Cualquier sugerencia estaría muy agradecido.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que el problema es simplemente permisos, concede permisos sobre `sys.database_permissions`:

```
USE master
GRANT SELECT ON sys.database_permissions TO <usuario>
GRANT CONTROL SERVER TO <usuario>
GO
```

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta en el caso de  sys.database_permissions el usuario requiere permisos "CONTROL SERVER" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187797.aspx

Comment: En efecto, es un tema de permisos.